# Catch exception with Crashlytics without crashing?

Tags: android, exception, crashlytics

In this particular release of my Android App, I do not want any crashes. I want to catch every exception and show a simple Toast message "Exception has occured" for it. Notwithstanding this, I still want to forward more details about each exception to my Crashlytics. How to do that?

I managed write my own all-catch method, in which I do what I wish and forward the exception to Crashlytics. The exceptions are recorded on Crashlytics, however the app indeed crashes, but I do not want it to crash.

Comment: So after it's crashed and you've displayed "Exception has occurred", what is your app going to do then?

Comment: Proceed with normal execution. Exceptions are not the end of the world, especially if you catch them.

Answer (score 10):

The answer of Luis Devies is outdated.
Its fairly simple. Just add `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);` and the Catch Block will appear in `CrashLytics` non fatal issues.

Extracted from [google documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=androidhttps://):

```
try {
   methodThatThrows();
} catch (Exception e) {
   FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
   // ...handle the exception.
}
```

Comment: FirebaseCrashlytics has no 'recordException' now, what to use now for same purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `Crashlytics.logException(Exception);` to your Catch Block it will appear in `Crashlytics` non fatal Issues.

Like this :

```
    try {
      myMethodThatThrows();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Crashlytics.logException(e);
      // handle your exception here! 
    }
```

Comment: Where should I put this code? I do not have any particular myMethodThatThrows(). There could be more than one myMethodThatThrows in my code, that, for one reason or another, do not have try block around them. What's worse, I do not know where they are located. Even more, I do not want users of this particular release of my app to experience any crashes. On a good side, I want to execute my own reporting routine (it emails stuff) for all those unhandled exceptions. In a nutshell, I need an all-catch method but without crashes.

Comment: If you wrote your own all-catch method, and you can have the exception there,you can put that code in there just be sure you pass the exception to the Crashlytics.logException function and it would be sent.